# Decoding the token doesn't give user profile

Tags: passport.js, auth0, express-jwt

I have been trying to solve this for several days.
I followed the tutorial in Auth0's documentation.

After decoding the token with express-jwt:

```
export let headerJWTCheck = expressJwt({
    secret: '*************************',
    audience: '******************************'
});
```

the content of req.user doesn't have the profile and roles that I need for role restrictions in the API.

Instead the content is in the form:

```
{ iss: 'https://******.eu.auth0.com/',
  sub: 'google-oauth2|***********************',
  aud: '********************',
  exp: **************,
  iat: **************}
```

In the front end I already get the user profile information I need, but I can't progress beyond that.

I'm using a function to restric the roles:

```
export function requireRole(role: string) {
return function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.user);
    var appMetadata = req.user.profile._json.app_metadata || {};
    var roles = appMetadata.roles || [];

    if (roles.indexOf(role) != -1) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.redirect('/unauthorized');
    }
}
```

but req.user.profile is always undefined.

In the main express application definition I have:

```
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    .................
}));
configurePassport();

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add the following code the auth0-lock configuration:

```
auth: {
    params: {
        scope: 'openid app_metadata roles'
    }
}
```

Which added the app_metadata and the roles array to **req.user** after decoding the token.

Answer (score 1):

The `express-jwt` library is initializing `req.user` based on the contents of the token that was included in the request.

If you require information at the `req.user` level you'll either need to [include that information directly on the token](https://auth0.com/docs/scopes#requesting-specific-claims) or do an enrichment of `req.user` before running the role checks. For example, you could enrich `req.user` by running additional code that gets the roles based on the `sub` claim (user identifier).